# What's the state of the art for scientific graphics on websites?

Tags: html, graphics, vector-graphics, qwt

Basically I want to build a web interface to a server-side math engine.  (Like a simplified version of QtOctave/GSL.)  But I haven't seen many resources to generate mathematical graphs on the client side--bar plots, heat maps, etc.  Support for this even in HTML5 seems to be lacking, as [this short discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/519518/HTML-JavaScript/HTML-scientific-typesetting-vector-graphics) suggests.  Is there any web equivalent to Qwt, jCharts, etc.?

Comment: So is it Protovis?  Going once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about Protovis?

http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/

Comment: Amazing library. Simply amazing.